# Вывод результата из getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Делаю запрос (В `data` лежит ключ и все необходимое для запроса):

```
function sendLanguageRequest() {
    let language;
    $.getJSON('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect', data).done(function (json) { language = json});
    return language;
}
```

Функция возвращает `undefined`.

Но если присвоение переменной мы заменим выводом результата в консоль то в консоли мы увидим результат.

```
function sendLanguageRequest() {
    $.getJSON('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect', data).done(function (json) { console.log(json)});
}
```

В консоли:

```
{code: 200, lang: "en"}
```

Как вывести это результат в переменную чтобы потом вывести через `return`?

P.S. Я видел подобные вопросы, но так и не нашел в них нормального ответа

---

Решение которым я пользуюсь выглядит так, но не позволяет выводить через `return`.

```
'use strict'
let language;
function sendLanguageRequest() {
    $.getJSON('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect', data, getLanguage);
    function getLanguage(response) {
        language = response.lang
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `$.getJSON` ... `.done` выполняется позже нежели выполняется `return language` и поэтому переменная пустая.

**Решение:** вместо переменной передать пришедший ответ в функцию `setLanguage(language)`:

```
function sendLanguageRequest()
{
    $.getJSON('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect', data)
        .done(function (json)
        {
            if(json.code == 200)
                setLanguage(json.lang)
        });
}

function setLanguage(language)
{
    //здесь делаете присвоение языка чему вам надо
}
```

Советую вам изучить [как работает AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Comment: Я сейчас использую подобный, но немного более короткий способ. Меня интересует как вывести результат в качестве `return` функции `sendLanguageRequest`

Comment: @brachkoff, я же вам написал в самом первом предложении причину того, почему это невозможно сделать так, как вы хотите. И решение я вам тоже ниже предоставил. Пожалуйста, прежде чем отвечать попытайтесь применить моё решение. Иначе вы не сможете вывести результат в качестве return функции sendLanguageRequest.

Comment: У меня есть собственное подобное решение, которое реализовано короче. Ваше же длиннее и как мое не позволяет вывести результат через `return`.

Comment: Я размещу свое решение в вопросе.

Comment: @brachkoff, насколько мне известно, свои решения вы должны размещать в качестве ответа самому себе. Иначе это выглядит уже не как вопрос. Я также дал вам точно такое же решение - вы передаёте точно также функцию как и в моём решении. Получается я потратил своё время и силы впустую, пытаясь вам помочь?

Comment: Получается что так. Но мое (как и ваше) решение не является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Именно поэтому я не могу добавить свое решение в ответ, ровно так же как отметить ваше.